# What do you call a dug up cageless pit where animals live in a zoo?

Tags: word-request

What do you call a dug up cageless pit where animals live in a zoo? Is there a specific words for it? You see this often in Zoo and it's often made for dangerous wild animals such as large primates.

Comment: Generally **a pit**                  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bear_pit

Comment: A pit is not 'dug up'. It is dug out, or excavated.

Comment: Such "prisons" will be rapidly going out of style in Anglophone countries, so I don't see much reason for a ***new*** term here. I'd just call them [***sunken enclosures***.](https://www.reddit.com/r/PlanetZoo/comments/dbh7rp/experimenting_with_sunken_enclosures/)